# error DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost. parse-server-example running on port 1337

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

im currently on the process of migrating parse.com to linode server(debian7).
i think i have correctly placed the mongo connection stringin index.js but still i get below message

```
DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.
parse-server-example running on port 1337.
```

here is what i have done as `root user` while installing parse on localmachine

```
git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example.git
cd parse-servear-example
npm install
```

replace the below lines

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
 serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
```

with

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://mongouser:PaSSwordD@100.100.200.200:27017/mydb',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
```

Starting the parseserver..

```
# npm start

> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /var/www/parse-server-example
> node index.js

DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.
parse-server-example running on port 1337.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the parse-server-example index.js you'll see the following lines above the creation of the new ParseServer object

```
var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}
```

which is where the console line output that you're seeing is coming from.

Comment: so is the configuration I've done is correct or does this mean that databaseUri variable is not set properly ?

Comment: The code I quoted is testing for two possible environment variables. If neither is present it prints out the "DATABASE_URI not specified" line. You then explicitly specify the URI in your code that creates the ParseServer object.